# Schema not being created when using Entity Framework 4.1 and Code First?

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am running tests against my context and thought EF 4.1 was supposed to create the schema for me in my database, it is not though. I am getting an error that db.Users does not exist in my database, but it is because it is not being created.

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my db connection string:

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=DIW-7-1;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Can you explain this: *I keep seeing this error inside the ServerVersion property of the DbContext*? How and where do you access `ServerVersion` property of `SqlConnection`?

Comment: @Ladislav, i apologize. I reworded my question. That had nothing to do with it, but at the time I thought it did.

Comment: So your database is created but tables are not?

Comment: Can you validate that you don't hide some exception during database creation?

Comment: Well, I am not doing anything explicitly in the code. I did run an SQL profiler on my database and never see it try to create the tables.

Comment: Did you change database initializer? What will happen if you try `context.Database.Delete();` followed by `context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();`? (just for test)

Comment: That worked. I am guessing the default action is to not create a schema if a DB already exists?

Comment: Yes! By asking if database is created but tables are not I meant if only database was created. EF code first is not able to initialize existing database - at least standard initializers don't do that.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: If you move your comments to an answer I for one will give you +1. Just ran into this issue myself and you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had a database created without tables so the default initializer was not dropping my database to create the tables. Thanks to [Ladislav Mrnka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413501/ladislav-mrnka) for the help, again!